# How to login just with "email" and "password" using identity-toolkit-php-client?

Tags: php, firebase

How to  login just with "email" and "password" using `identity-toolkit-php-client`? The class `Gitkit_Clien` ask you for email (`getUserByEmail`) but not for (`getUserBypassword`). Please help me out here.

pd: just php support please, there is `firebase` `sdk` `por` `php`, but it does not have User Authentication (well yeah, but not the one with email and password)

Comment: I did it with guzzle xD....

Answer (score 0):

I did it with guzzle. xD

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-sign-in-email-password

xD xD xD ....